# Browser activity simulator

Tags: ruby, http, web, browser, simulator

For testing purpose, I'm looking for a tool that simulates browsing activity. I'm not  looking for just HTTP(S) traffic generator, I need to define some browsing scenarios. For example, to browse [x] links deep, or randomly jump from page to page, or to randomly fill and submit forms, maybe even generate some erroneous requests. It's important to support all HTTP verbs (PUT, HEAD, DELETE, ...etc.), and hopefully, but not necessarily, command line. It'd be a very big plus to have randomizable fields (IP address, User-Agent, ...etc.)

If no such tool exist, what are the recommended packages to script such in ruby?

Answer (score 0):

This is called "end to end" web testing (e2e)

You may want to look at [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), a technology that is able to take control of a browser and automate user browsing scenarios.

Selenium is usually used through some kind of control tool. Since you use ruby, you may want to look at [selenium-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver)

If you want random interactions, I heard of a tool called [gremlins](https://github.com/marmelab/gremlins.js/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into capybara https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

You can use capybara with the most common ruby test frameworks, rspec, cucumber, test::unit...

It supports selenium by default but you can also make it headless (not opening a browser window) if you use another driver such as capybara-webkit.

Check you the README, you'll find everything you need.